# ¿No existe la clase "hidden-md-down" en el nuevo bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Quiero usar la clase   .hidden-md-down pero no existe en el nuevo bootstrap.min.css.

No se si hay alguna que la sustituye...

Answer (score 2):

Según la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities) se han **eliminado** todas las clases: `.hidden-*` en Bootstrap 4.

Ahora se usan las clases `.d-*`

Para más información ver los ejemplos: [common-display-values](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#common-display-values)

Answer (score 2):

Las clases hidden-* y visible-* ya no existen en Bootstrap 4 Beta.

Si desea ocultar un elemento en niveles específicos o puntos de interrupción en Bootstrap 4, use las clases d-*

En tu caso:

> hidden-md-down -- > d-none d-lg-block